# How to use two forms and submit once?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Is it possible to have two forms with two submit buttons such that when I click on the button it saves the input fields in both forms?

I'm concerning to solve this in PHP / MySQL.

I tried my own way:

```
if ((isset($_POST["form-1"])) && (isset($_POST["form-2"])) {
    //SQL Insertion 
}
```

Comment: No it's not possible you can submit only one form at a time.

Comment: yes , i know i can make a unit form , but i must use two different forms , and these forms are not respective

Comment: Mac, Can U specify the main reaso u r using two forms and need to submit them at one click.. if this gets clear solution could me more comprehensive....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you can only submit one form at a time.

If you have to use two forms, the only way to do this would be to clone the second form's fields into the first one using jQuery. Won't work when JS is turned off, though.

See [Copying from form to form in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435852/copying-from-form-to-form-in-jquery)

Why do you need two forms?

Comment: actually i should use two forms , because the original scripts , im working with, require two different forms  and i cant combine them into a unit one ,  how is the way in jquery  !?

Comment: *(nitpicking)* you don't need jQuery to combine the forms. Can be done with JavaScript alone, too ;)

Comment: @Gordon true. The jQuery virus is getting to me. I am spending too much time on SO. :)

Comment: @Pekka judging by your reputation gain since you registered, I can very much second that ;)

Comment: @Gordon true... but it was worth it! I've learned a ton as well. :)

Comment: @MAC UR WISH IS MY COMMAND :D

Answer (score 3):

If you have a problem like this, the design is flawed.

You can submit only one form at a time for a reason.

Change the design to use only one form; doing workarounds to submit two anyway is a horrible practice that would be better to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving similar result would be to club the two forms into a single one and have 2 submit buttons with different values and same `name="submit"` field.

toFoo.html :

```
<form action="doFoo.php">
    User <input type="text" name="username" />
    Pass <input type="password name="password" />

    <!-- Submit one -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create user" />

    <!-- some more of your fields or whatever -->
    <input type="text" name="blah" value="bleh" />

    <!-- Submit two -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login user" />
</form>
```

doFoo.php :

```
<?php
if( $_POST["submit"] == "Login user" ) {
    //do login foo    
}
if( $_POST["submit"] == "Create user" ) {
    //do signup foo 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could submit both forms at the same time via Ajax but your php script would only receive one form at a time. Better to just convert your 2 forms into one big form if you need all inputs going to one script

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know only one form can be submitted at a time. You could try wrapping them in one form.

Answer (score 0):

A submit button submits only fields of the form it lives in. If you need content of both forms, you'll have to copy the fields from other form to some hidden field in the form where submit button was clicked. This can quite easily be done in JavaScript.