# my code wont update after search

Tags: php, html, mysql

can anyone help me find the code thats causing my code not to work? my code wont update... ive been debuging this code for 3hours already stil cant fix it :(...i need your help guys.

php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['gogo'])){
include('include/connect.php');
$batchcode = $_GET['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode = '".$batchcode."' ");
if($sql) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id[] = $rows['id'];
        $name[] = $rows['name'];
        $score1[] = $rows['score1'];
        $score2[] = $rows['score2'];
        $other_qual[] = $rows['score3'];
        $interview[] = $rows['score4'];
        $total[] = $rows['total'];
    }
}
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
include('include/connect.php');
//1
$u1id = $_POST['id1'];
$u1name = $_POST['name1'];
$u1score1 = $_POST['optA1'];
$u1score2 = $_POST['optB1'];
$u1other_qual = $_POST['other_qual1'];
$u1interview = $_POST['interview1'];
$u1total = $_POST['total1'];
//2
$u2id = $_POST['id2'];
$u2name = $_POST['name2'];
$u2score1 = $_POST['optA2'];
$u2score2 = $_POST['optB2'];
$u2other_qual = $_POST['other_qual2'];
$u2interview = $_POST['interview2'];
$u2total = $_POST['total2'];
//1
mysql_query("UPDATE score SET score1='$u1score1', score2='$u1score2', total='$u1total' WHERE id='$u1id'");
//2
mysql_query("UPDATE score SET score1='$u2score1', score2='$u2score2', total='$u2total' WHERE id='$u2id'");

header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

html code:

```
<form method="get">
<form method="post">
Search batchcode: <input type="text" name="code" id="query" /><input type="submit" value="Go" name="gogo" /><br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ID: <br />
<input type="text" name="id1" value="<?php if(empty($id[0])){$id[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="id2" value="<?php if(empty($id[1])){$id[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="name1" value="<?php if(empty($name[0])){$name[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="name2" value="<?php if(empty($name[1])){$name[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $name[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 1: <br />
<input type="text" name="optA1" value="<?php if(empty($score1[0])){$score1[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score1[0];} ?>" onchange="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optA2" value="<?php if(empty($score1[1])){$score1[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score1[1];} ?>" onchange="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Score 2: <br />
<input type="text" name="optB1" value="<?php if(empty($score2[0])){$score2[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score2[0];} ?>" onchange="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="optB2" value="<?php if(empty($score2[1])){$score2[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $score2[1];} ?>" onchange="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Other Qualification: <br />
<input type="text" name="other_qual1" value="<?php if(empty($other_qual[0])){$other_qual[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $other_qual[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="other_qual2" value="<?php if(empty($other_qual[1])){$other_qual[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $other_qual[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Interview: <br />
<input type="text" name="interview1" value="<?php if(empty($interview[0])){$interview[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $interview[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="interview2" value="<?php if(empty($interview[1])){$interview[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $interview[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>
<td>
Total: <br />
<input type="text" name="total1" value="<?php if(empty($total[0])){$total[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[0];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal1()" /> <br />
<input type="text" name="total2" value="<?php if(empty($total[1])){$total[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $total[1];} ?>" readonly onKeyUp="optTotal2()" /> <br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="update" name="update" />
</form>
</form>
```

Comment: I smell a troll in our midst.....not even a real question XD

Comment: Nice SQL injection `?code=1' OR '1'='1`

Comment: What does "not work" and "won't update" mean?  Are you seeing errors in the logs, do you get unexpected values in the db?

Comment: Well, the update part can't work! You have whitespace before the `header()`. Hint: Look at `?>\n<?php`

Comment: @Barbara Laird it doesnt show any error...my update code was working before i put this search code thing and now it wont work.

Comment: Where's your form `action` attribute?

Comment: @MElliott does that attribute necessary?

Comment: Well I suppose not.. assuming you are posting to the same page right? I think it will still work and post itself to the same page.  I think the requirement for action is only by standards. However you might just include it anyway to be safe.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck where did you find that ?>\n<?php

Comment: I think your problem is that you can't use method `GET` and `POST` at the same time..  See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php

Comment: @MElliott i guess so but if i remove the get method my search function wont work? do you have some ways to make it work?

Comment: `?>\n<?php` is between the "gogo" and the "update" section. The line break comes **before** the `header()` command at the end of the "update" section, rendering it dysfunctional.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do a GET and POST at the same time.  Use one or the other..

In your HTML remove the `<form method="get">` and the corresponding `</form>` and just use POST. (`<form method="post">`)

See this: [Post and get at the same time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php)

So then in your PHP, change `GET` to `POST` like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['gogo'])){
include('include/connect.php');
$batchcode = $_POST['code'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM score WHERE batchcode = '".$batchcode."' ");
...
```

**EDIT:**

Or alternatively, you could keep your php code the same the way you have it and just make it 2 seperate forms in your HTML,.. The search form using `GET` and the other form using `POST`

So HTML would be this:

```
<form method="get">
Search batchcode: <input type="text" name="code" id="query" /><input type="submit" value="Go" name="gogo" /><br />
</form>

<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ID: <br />
<input type="text" name="id1" value="<?php if(empty($id[0])){$id[0] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[0];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
<input type="text" name="id2" value="<?php if(empty($id[1])){$id[1] = array(NULL);}else{echo $id[1];} ?>" readonly /> <br />
</td>...
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code won't update then it is very likely you are updating the wrong files. Make sure that you are updating the files on the server or even better updating the files on your local drive and then uploading them to the server.

Check that you have permissions to upload to the correct place too. Might be that your uploads are failing because of bad permissions.