# Action can't load the correct page (url)

Tags: php, forms, redirect, action

With the code below I printed out a friendshiprequest on someone's page, for example: friendrequests.php?user_id=4.

The problem: When I click on the 'accept' button I have to stay on that page, but the 'user_id=4' dissapears.

In the action tags of the form I typed  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and I also typed the url manually (to test), but that also didn't work.

```
foreach ($friendrequests as $request) {

                        echo "<div><p><a href='profile.php?user_id=".$request['friendship_applicant_id']."'><img src='uploads/" . $request['friendship_applicant_avatar']  . " " . " ' alt='' />" . $request['friendship_applicant_surname'] . " " . $request['friendship_applicant_name'].  "</a> has send you a friend request"   . "<form action='' type='post'><button type='submit' name=''>Accept</button><button type='submit'  name='' >Decline</button></form></p></div>";   



                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use POST but want to preserve GET parameters at the same time. This can't be done automatically when `action=""`.

This answer should work for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749442/2948573

Here's a better formatted working example, using the "REQUEST_URI" variable:

```
foreach ($friendrequests as $request) {
    echo "
        <div><p>
            <a href='profile.php?user_id=".$request['friendship_applicant_id']."'>
                <img src='uploads/" . $request['friendship_applicant_avatar']  . " " . " ' alt='' />" . $request['friendship_applicant_surname'] . " " . $request['friendship_applicant_name'] . "
            </a> has send you a friend request" . "
            <form action='" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "' method='post'>
                <button type='submit' name=''>Accept</button>
                <button type='submit' name=''>Decline</button>
            </form>
        </p></div>";   
}
```

Comment: <form action='friendrequests.php?user_id=4' method='post'>

When I replace the type by method and type the url manually it's working but when i type $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in the action tags it always gives a syntax error... thanks in advance!

Comment: method instead of type? :)

Comment: Yep, I omitted that. :)

Comment: Well, it's working. Thank you! 
What's the difference between REQUEST_URI EN PHP_SERVER SELF?

Comment: You can find it here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php Basically REQUEST_URI returns the whole URI given and PHP_SELF just the path to the file (excluding the ? part)