# How can I get a content of input and insert into a URL with php?

Tags: php

I need insert data in a database and search in one input. All at once.

I used `method="post"` because the input with `name="q"` insert data in database with `$_POST`. But i need use `$_GET + $_POST` in this form.

My index.php

```
<form action="search.php?q=<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                            <input 
                                   required
                                   dir="ltr"
                                   name="q"
                                   class="input is-large" 
                                   type="text">
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <input type="submit" class="button is-color is-large" value="Buscar" name="go">
                        </form>
```

So, i am trying use `$_GET['q']` to complete the form action with content of input. But not working.

I need that url stay like this: **`search.php?q=CONTENT OF INPUT`** after submit.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `$_GET`?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: because i need use $_POST to insert data in mysql. i need make 2 actions, post and get

Comment: Well, you can't do two actions in one request.  That's impossible.  You *could* do a `POST search.php?q=something` with JavaScript, but I don't follow why you'd want to.  A URL like `search.php` sounds like a `GET` action to me.

Comment: This is a duplicate question please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749406/post-and-get-at-the-same-time-in-php

Comment: You don't need two actions. URL parameters are available in $_GET even with the request uses post

Answer (score 1):

alternatively to Dng's answer, you can do this:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" autocomplete="off">
```

you can have something like:

```
search.php?q=textbox_value_here&go=Buscar
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `$_GET` here.
You just get the value of the input has `name="q"` from form at `search.php` like `$_POST["q"]` then do what you want with it.