# Validating 2 forms with a single button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery Validation plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. Is it possible to validate 2 forms with a single button using this plugin. I find this plugin very useful, but am not sure how to achieve validating 2 forms together.

```
<form>
    <legend>Shipping</legend>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <textarea id="address" rows="4"></textarea>
</form>
<form>
    <legend>Billing</legend>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name"></input>
    <br/>
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <textarea id="address" rows="4"></textarea>
</form>
<br/><br/>
<button type="submit">Validate the Forms</button>
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5bkuw/

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719987/how-to-use-two-forms-and-sumit-once) - Not neccessarily an answer to *your* question but it certainly applies to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

put a button

```
   <input type="button" onClick="validateForms()"/>


function validateForms()
{

  $('#form1').valid();
  $('#form2').valid();
}
```

Comment: Thanks PSR, but I think it should be .valid(), .valid works fine

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth, The inline JavaScript `onClick` is pretty sloppy when you're already using jQuery.  Just use a `click` event with [jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks PSR for hinting this function, but this one worked

```
<input type="button" onClick="validateForms()"/>


function validateForms()
{

  $('#form1').valid();
  $('#form2').valid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, the best way would be to eliminate the sloppy inline JavaScript code entirely and replace it with a jQuery `click` event handler.  [See:  http://api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xVM6a/**

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        $('#form1').valid();
        $('#form2').valid();
    });

});
```