# Repositioning multipart/form-data submit button

Tags: javascript, css, forms, form-submit, multipartform-data

I've got the following structure:

```
<form id="the_form" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="1">blabla</table>
    <table id="2">blabla
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
    </table>
</form>
<table id="3'>
    <form>here are a couple of subforms</form>
</table>
```

Visually I would like to achieve this structure:

```
<form id="the_form" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="1">blabla</table>
    <table id="2">blabla
    </table>
</form>
<table id="3>
    <form>here are a couple of subforms</form>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' />
</table>
```

I can't change the way the forms are structured. I tried to put the input in a noscript and then make a link that submits the form but I think this doesn't work due to the fact that the form is a multipart/form-data. So how do I solve this? Does anybody know a css way to place the table 2 under 3 (table 3 has a non-fixed height, seems messy to fix this with javascript so I hope somebody has a better solution)? Or is there a javascript/jquery way to do this? Or am I over-thinking this and is there a simple solution?

Cheers,
Adnan

Comment: Is there multiple forms (i.e. one form posts to "/a.php" and another to "/b.php") or do all the form fields nee to be sent in one request, to the same url?

Comment: Why do you need 2 form tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery (you should add it to the question's tags, by the way, since you are open to using it as a solution), you can decide which forms to submit when.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719987/how-to-use-two-forms-and-sumit-once) if you have ideas re submitting multiple forms at once.

You can also use [AJAX to submit form data to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) "on your own terms", without using the archaic `<form>` construct (with mandatory page redirection/refresh).

Submitting a form with jQuery looks like this:

```
$('#yourFormID').submit();
```

You can also change your Submit button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` and then do something like this:

```
$('#thesubmitbutton`).click(function() {
     //check if all fields filled out, like this:
     var somefield = $('#somefield').val();
     if (somefield == '') {
          alert('Please complete all form fields');
          return false;
     }else{
          $('#myform1').submit();
     }
});
```

However, if you have multiple forms, you might want to check out how to do things with AJAX -- it's much simpler than many folks imagine.  [See this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843) for some simple examples to get you started.