# jQuery - Copying form to identical form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to copy an existing form to another form.  I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435852/copying-from-form-to-form-in-jquery) which works on normal inputs but it throws an error on my checkboxes

The jQuery function ([from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436375/94278)) I am using is

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.copyNamedTo = function(other) {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(':input[name]', this).each(function() {
                $('[name=' + $(this).attr('name') +']', other).val($(this).val())
            })
        })
    }
}(jQuery));
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=cartype[]]
```

The checkboxes are arranged like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cartype[]" id="cartype_10" value="10">4x4
<input type="checkbox" name="cartype[]" id="cartype_11" value="11">Saloon
```

I expect this is due to the `[]` in the name but can't figure out what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to replace the `[` and `]` in your name with `\\[` and `\\]` (as laid out [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)), as (as you know) they've got special meanings in jQuery selectors.

```
$('[name=' + $(this).attr('name').replace(/([\[\]])/g, '\\\\$1') +']', other).val($(this).val())
```

Note that technically you should also have a selector of the form `$('[name="val"]')` (note the quotes around the attribute value). jQuery has always seemed to be lenient about this, but it's conforming to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

To nail the checkboxes and radio buttons, you need to be setting the `checked` property of them, rather than altering the value. You can change your function to this;

```
$.fn.copyNamedTo = function(other) {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(':input[name]', this).each(function() {
            var target = $('[name=' + $(this).attr('name').replace(/([\[\]])/g, '\\\\$1') +']', other);

            // Radios have the same name as each other, so filter based on value
            // Checkboxes are in the same boat here due to the naming conventions shown in the OP.
            if ($(this).is(':checkbox, :radio')) {
                target.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
            } else {
                target.val($(this).val());
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This worked, in that it didnt error. But none of the checkboxes actually copied the data across. Thinking about it all my form elements have unique IDs so maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: @Chris: Try with the quotes (second part of my answer). Obviously you'll need some prefix/ suffix for the second form to keep the ID's unique, but you could change the selector to `$('#prefix' + this.id).val($(this).val())`.

Comment: Hey Matt.. You updated it just as I posted my comment, I edited it to reflect your edit.  Cheers mate

Comment: The second form is loaded via ajax, so I have a parent by which to identify them by. Which works fine.

Comment: Hey Matt, this worked perfectly... BUT for one set of checkboxes it didnt work (but another set it did work?!) There was no errors. P.s. as per your suggestion you do need " around the value i.e. `$('[name="val"]')`

Comment: @Chris: Can you provide the markup for the checkboxes that failed?

Comment: Its the cartype ones that I put in my original question.  I realise that it works for every element EXCEPT checkboxes that are linked (as the car type ones are). Im wondering if for them I should just use the unique ID? P.s. thanks again for your help :D - FYI I put a special case in for "cartype" and made it use the ID and it all works

Comment: @Chris: Ahhh I see. The updated code in my answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data` attribute.

`data-name="cartype[]"`

And grab it using: `$(this).data('name')`