# Submit same inputs to same action

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have input sets with same names, and i need to submit thems to same action. When i try to submit that forms, only one form is posted.

Like this:

```
<form id="form1"  name="form1" action="aaa.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /> </form>

<form id="form2"  name="form2" action="aaa.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" /> </form>
```

Comment: So whats wrong..You have created two different forms.For each form different submit event will get executed.I dont see any valid requirement submitting two forms on submit action.Plz elaborate.Y dont you put everything under single form and then submit whole form?

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity here. Shouldn't the name of the two forms should be the same and name of the two inputs - different (unless they are radio buttons for example)?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can submit only one form at a time. Besides, your fields have the exact same name so it doesn't make much sense to submit both.

You could [clone the fields of your second form into the first form using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1436375/2612112), though it wouldn't work if the user has JavaScript disabled in his browser. That or wrapping all your fields into one form, calling the first two fields `id_product_1` and `add_1` and  the second two `id_product_2` and `add_2` respectively, for example.

But in all, it sounds like you have a design problem.